# My app keeps crashing because of low memory warning, How to use GPUImage in a memory efficient way?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I'm trying to make a simple photo editor with `GPUImage`. I have two issues. One is that app keeps *crashing whenever I slide the sliders for brightness or contrast a little ahead*. On simulator i don't face these problems but then comes the second issue. The image turns in landscape orientation (I have no idea why) when memory low warning shows on console. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I read on forums, here and on github that many users are facing memory issues so maybe it's a memory leak in the library? I am new to iOS development so yeah I'd like you guys to be elaborate about it. p.s. i am using iphone 4s and ios 7

```
//The Action List
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    GPUImageFilter *selectedFilter;
    //GPUImageBrightnessFilter *brightnessFilter;
    //GPUImageContrastFilter *contrastFilter;
    //GPUImageSaturationFilter *saturationFilter;
    //sliderValue = 0.0;
    bool choiceChecker = NO;
    bool choiceChecker1 = NO;
    bool choicechecker2 = NO;
    //self.stepper.value = 0;

    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
            selectedFilter = [[GPUImageGrayscaleFilter alloc] init];
            break;
        case 1:
            selectedFilter = [[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];
            break;
        case 2:
            selectedFilter = [[GPUImageSketchFilter alloc] init];
            break;
        case 3:
            selectedFilter = [[GPUImagePixellateFilter alloc] init];
            break;
        case 4:
            selectedFilter = [[GPUImageColorInvertFilter alloc] init];
            break;
        case 5:
            selectedFilter = [[GPUImageToonFilter alloc] init];
            break;
        case 6:
            selectedFilter = [[GPUImagePinchDistortionFilter alloc] init];
            break;
        case 7:
            choiceChecker1 = YES;
            break;
        case 8:
            choiceChecker = YES;
            break;
        case 9:

            choicechecker2 = YES;
            break;
        case 10:
            selectedFilter = [[GPUImageFilter alloc] init];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    //UIImage *selectedImage =
    UIImage *filteredImage;

    //for brightness
    if(choiceChecker1 == YES)
    {
        self.brightnessSlider.hidden = NO;
        self.contrastSlider.hidden = YES;
        self.saturationSlider.hidden = YES;
        [self.imageView setImage:originalImage];
        NSLog(@"hello");

    }
    //for contrast
    else if(choiceChecker == YES)
    {
        self.contrastSlider.hidden = NO;
        self.brightnessSlider.hidden = YES;
        self.saturationSlider.hidden = YES;
        //[self.imageView setImage:originalImage];

    }
    //for saturation
    else if(choicechecker2 == YES)
    {
        self.saturationSlider.hidden = NO;
        self.brightnessSlider.hidden = YES;
        self.contrastSlider.hidden = YES;
        [self.imageView setImage:originalImage];
    }
    //for filters
    else if (choiceChecker == NO && choiceChecker1 == NO && choicechecker2 == NO)
    {
    filteredImage = [selectedFilter imageByFilteringImage:originalImage];
    [self.imageView setImage:filteredImage];
    originalImage = filteredImage;
    }
}

//  Edited action listener for brightness slider (testView is a GPUImageView)
-(IBAction)BrightnessSlid:(UISlider *)slider {
     sliderValue = self.brightnessSlider.value;
     //self.contrastSlider.hidden = YES;
     fx_image = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:originalImage];
     [brightnessFilter setBrightness:sliderValue];

      [fx_image addTarget:brightnessFilter];
      [brightnessFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
     [brightnessFilter forceProcessingAtSize:CGSizeMake(320.0, 519.0)];
    [fx_image processImage];


     [fx_image addTarget:testView];
     [self.imageView addSubview:testView];
     final_image = [brightnessFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];
     //originalImage = final_image;
      }
```

Comment: Have you tried using Instruments or the Static Analyser? Both are very good at helping with these.

Comment: Okay I'm going to try those tools. But do you spot anything in the code which might be memory exhausting? 'Cus I don't. though some guys were going on about how memory consuming is GPUImagepicture type.

Comment: Try the static analyser first. It's really good at spotting memory that needs releasing and isn't being released. I can't see anything from reading through but I'm not an expert at image stuff.

Comment: Make sure that you don't create too many autoreleased images - they will be released only when you exit the current call from the run loop. Better use [[xxx alloc] init] for anything large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing that leaps out at me is your slider method, which is horribly inefficient. You're creating a new GPUImagePicture and resulting UIImage every single time that fires. You don't want to do that.

Instead, instantiate your GPUImagePicture once, target it to the appropriate filter once, and adjust values as needed in your slider. Have the output be targeted to a GPUImageView instead of a UIImageView. This will avoid wasteful image creation and destruction on every move of the slider, and will prevent expensive trips through Core Graphics at either end. By itself, that will save you a lot of memory and dramatically improve your slider preview performance.

You may also want to think about processing your image at a lower resolution, to match your output view's resolution. No need to process pixels you won't see. This can be done using `-forceProcessingAtSize:` on your filter.

You'll need to remember to disconnect filters from the GPUImagePicture and GPUImageView when you swap them out, and to use `-processImage` on the GPUImagePicture every time you want to update the preview image.

Comment: I edited the slider method. At least now app is not crashing but now brightness is not being applied and slider is still not smooth.

Comment: @NSNoob - You're still not doing what I stated above. You're creating a new GPUImagePicture every single time your slider updates, and then capturing a UIImage from the filtered result. The only code that should appear in your slider is an update to the brightness filter's brightness property and a -processImage call on your GPUImagePicture. No other lines of code should be present. Rearchitect your code to do that. See the SimpleImageFilter example in the GPUImage examples to see how to do this.